# Flask Gunicorn Docker app running on a vps can't be accessed via its public IPv4 IP

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, vps

so I have a simple flask app running with gunicorn and I want it to run on my VPS. This is the command that I use to run gunicorn:

`CMD [ "gunicorn", "-w" , "4", "app:create_app()", "--bind=0.0.0.0:80"]`

and this is my app.py:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True

    @app.route("/")
    def index():
        return render_template("index.html")

    return app
```

When I run it on my VPS, I get confirmation that it is running on http://0.0.0.0:80 but I can't seem to access it via my VPS's public IPv4 address

```
[2023-12-16 22:19:28 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-12-16 22:19:28 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:80 (1)
[2023-12-16 22:19:28 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-12-16 22:19:28 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
[2023-12-16 22:19:28 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
[2023-12-16 22:19:28 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
[2023-12-16 22:19:28 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
```

I tried accessing the public IPv4 address with different ports and it still doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: how did you configure `docker`? It may need to redirect ports.

Comment: Do you mean the dockerfile? The dockerfile has standard instructions of copying files, setting working dir, downloading requirements.txt, and running the app using gunicorn.

Comment: as I remember `docker` may not gives access to port inside image and it may need to run it as `docker run -p 80:80 ...` - see [published-ports](https://docs.docker.com/network/#published-ports). In `dockfile` it may need command like `EXPOSE 80:80`